# Did oracle error cause Linux system can ping but cannot ssh?

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh, ping

We have seen this same strange problem twice so far.

First we found our remote Linux server responds to `ping` but we could not `ssh` to it. We went to the server and found the system unresponsive, and had to restart it. After we restarted it, we checked the log. We found nothing in the `/var/log/message` log, but we found some error messages in Oracle's `*_alert.log` files:

```
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 296280
Private strand flush not complete
Current log# 3 seq# 296279 mem# 0: /home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo03.log
Current log# 3 seq# 296279 mem# 1: /home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo09.log
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 296280 (LGWR switch)
Current log# 2 seq# 296280 mem# 0: /home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
Current log# 2 seq# 296280 mem# 1: /home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo08.log
Process P098 died, see its trace file
Process P098 died, see its trace file
Process P098 died, see its trace file
```

Our questions are:

1. Could Oracle cause Linux to hang? I thought even if Oracle is dead, Linux should be alive. We thought this is relevant because these events happened at the same time i.e. Oracle died before Linux hung.
2. What could be the reason for the server to respond to `ping` but not allow `ssh` to it?
   We did a test when the `ssh` login failed, and it showed port 22 was okay:

   ```
   [administrator@localhost ~]$ nc -v -w 1 172.16.*.* -z 22
   Connection to 172.16.*.* 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
   ```

   When we do `ssh -v`, it stops at "load ssh key".

3.Why a linux server is hang,but it can still be `ping`?How can we prevent system hang?

Any ideas what could be the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log snippet you showed doesn't say the database crashed; it looks like a delay in a log switch, and a [parallel query slave process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/bgprocesses.htm) dying. That should certainly be investigated - you can start by looking at the trace file - but it could be a symptom rather than the cause.

A very high load can make the server behave like this, responding to some network events, but unable to (or extremely slow to) create new processes. That would explain why you can connect to port 22 but sshd isn't progressing very far and doesn't complete the connection process. It could also explain your `P098` dying - it might not be ale to start in the first place.

It's unlikely that Oracle would be causing this directly. It's more likely that you have a script or application process which is spinning for some reason, spawning new processes until the system runs put of resources. (You can certainly get an infinite loop in a PL/SQL block, which would cause high load, but wouldn't cause you to run out of processes - so you'd be able to connect eventually). You could be getting an ORA error that is making a script/app loop if it isn't handled well, but you'd have to hope that's revealed in an application log. It might not even be something that's talking to the DB.

It's basically impossible to know what happened if it wasn't logged. You might have a starting point if you know what was being run at the time. You could also look back at what the DB was doing before the problem, with the AWR reports in Oracle Enterprise Manager, for example.

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do to recover if you can't connect, and even if you have an existing shell running you might not be able to run useful tools to see what's going on. Sometimes a hard reboot is the only option, though obviously it's a last resort.

Comment: I also guess maybe some pl/sql get wrong, but we did not found which one. Now we restart our server and will use top command to check it  everyday to see if the cpu goes very high. does it prevent system hang?

Comment: @snow8261 - `top` only tells you what's happening, it doesn't prevent anything. You can set resource limits in Linux (e.g. `nproc` in `limits.conf` or via `ulimit -u`; see `man ulimit`) or in the database (with [resource manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm), and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/os.htm) might be of interest too). Understand what they will do before implementing though! A single statement, even a PL/SQL block, might cause higher than normal load but wouldn't normally spawn processes.

Comment: Thanks,it seems like both the linux and oracle have to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes oracle can hang your system if the process load is very high. Please let us know that do you have multipath on this system with oracle or RACK.

Comment: Do you have oracleasm also in this. if yes then please update the package the package as per the kernel. and please update the oracle to

Comment: there is only one oralce in our system and no rac